# Huge Pages causing Ubuntu 20.04 crashes

Tags: kernel, vmware

I have Ubuntu 20.04.  I have configured Huge Pages by adding the following to sysctl.conf:
kernel.shmmax = 8589934592
vm.nr_hugepages = 4096
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 1001

and, adding the following to limits.conf

- soft memlock 8388608
- hard memlock 8388608

When I rebooted, I received a "Failed to Start Apply Kernel Variables" timeout error

On research, I found that I needed to add the following to sysctl.conf:

DefaultTimeoutStartSec = 90s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec = 90s

and that resolved the boot error.

However, after logging into the OS and waiting a few minutes, the desktop will go unresponsive and I will need to reboot the system.

I though that based on "free" and "lscpu" that I should increase the RAM and processors of the VM running Ubuntu, so I raised the RAM from 12GB to 16GB, and the processors from 2 with 1 core each, to 2 with 4 cores each.

I rebooted fine and "free" and "lscpu" showed the changes.  However, after several minutes, VMWare popped up an alert window stating that "The CPU has been disabled by the guest OS".

Any help in this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.